# Doubt when compiling USB/IP drivers

Tags: kernel, compiling, drivers

I need to install a USB 3G modem to a Windows virtual machine (running on OVM).
The modem will be plugged on a Linux host. (Would Windows be easier?)

I don't understand what the following README file says.

```
For newer kernels ( >=2.6.28 ), try linux-staging code!

This directory contains the source code of usbip drivers for mainline kernel.

[How to make USB/IP drivers]
    1. cd $(top)/drivers/{version}/

    2. make KSOURCE=/usr/src/kernel-source-2.6.20

            KSOURCE is the directory that your kernel was built.

    3. If succeed, usbip_common_mod.ko, vhci-hcd.ko and usbip.ko are built.

    4. Copy these kernel modules to client and server hosts.

    5. Don't forget to make USB/IP tools. See $(top)/src/README.
```

The result of my `cat /proc/version` is:

```
Linux version 2.6.39-400.209.1.el6uek.x86_64 (mockbuild@ca-build44.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) )
```

What is this `linux-staging code`? It says I'll need it.

Another thing is that the `MAKE` call requires the `KSOURCE` location, but I've checked it and it's empty.

I should download and extract the `2.6.39` kernel source there, right?

Where should I put the generated .ko files as instructed by item 4?

Comment: The `.ko` files are going to go in one of the subdirectories under here: `ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel`.

Comment: How will I know what subdirectories should they go? I took a look and there are many, even under `../kernel/drivers/usb/`

Comment: There's usually a target in the make file, `make install` that will do this for you.